# What is the right overall name for personas, task analysis, mental model diagrams

Tags: terminology

When you are analyzing your collected design research data there are a variety of ways to do it. I'm looking for a way to label personas, task analysis, mental model diagrams and similar. Would you call it data visualization, analytic tools, models or frameworks? What are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**User Research Deliverables** is a pretty common term for such things.

Answer (score 1):

Personas and models are quite different types of tools. 
So, I wouldn't call them "models". They aren't "frameworks" either.

I would go with **Design research data**. The main point is that it would be understandable for you and your client/user. Even if it's not the most accurate terminology.